# How to send 'custom variables' parameters in Measurement Protocol(GA)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm develop on a html5 project. The project is an news reading html5 site. It has offline reading feature, now we need to integration the Google analzyer to get the user access report.

But we found the GA js sdk do not support  offline function.

Then I try to get more information on the GA help site. I found the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) can help to do this.

It's said we can send the GA request through the API. But I stop again on the develop process, because we need to send custom variables like JS SDK:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'user-online', 1, 1]);
```

I've checked on the GA help site but not any informations about the "Custom Variables".

I think [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs) should be of help but there are no more detail sample code to explain the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics (UA) is what the Measurement Protocol drives. They've changed quite a few things. Not sure about the accuracy of the other elements of this article, but it is correct about the fact that Custom Dimensions have replaced Custom Variables in UA https://www.optimizesmart.com/beginners-guide-to-universal-analytics-creating-custom-dimensions-metrics/

Head here to read about Custom Dimensions https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_

Answer (score -2):

Did you read this? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar

It's name, value and scope, identical to the old analytics

Comment: The original question was specifically regarding the Measurement Protocol https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide